# Where to use stellen and where fragen

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Both words `stellen` and `fragen` have the meaning `to ask`.
Is there any rule, when to use each of those words ? Or are they complete synonyms and can be freely switched ?

Comment: You are mistaken here. "stellen" is not synonymous to "ask". But "stellen" is a verb that accompanies "Frage": "Er stellt eine Frage." => "He asks a question."

Comment: Can you add the source where you found both meaning "to ask", please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Eine Frage stellen* is the same as *fragen*. You use the former when you want to stress the fact that you're asking or to avoid a sentence without object: *Er stellte eine Frage.* instead of *Er fragte.* (which likely prompts *Was fragte er denn?*).

*Stellen* by itself means *to put*.

Answer (score 5):

"Stellen" actually means "to put". You can combine it with "eine Frage".

- **"eine Frage stellen"** = "to ask a question", or literally "to put a question"
- **"fragen"** = "to ask"

Ich frage. - I ask. / I am asking.
Ich stelle eine Frage. - I ask a question. / I am asking a question.

Ich frage meine Mutter. - I ask my mum. / I am asking my mum.
Ich stelle meiner Mutter eine Frage. - I ask my mum a question. / I am asking my mum a question.
*(Side note: "eine Frage" is the accusative object, "meiner Mutter" is the dative object - the person who "receives" something, is always in the dative case.)*

Comment: In return there's also "antworten" and "eine Antwort geben" which both mean to answer.

Comment: So I can stelle eine Frage but I can't frage eine Frage? Is the latter grammatically incorrect or is it merely avoided because it sounds odd?